# Does (or, how does) MySQL natively take care of concurrent transactions?

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency

Maybe this is an obvious question, but it's just something I'm unsure of. If I have two standalone PHP applications running on one LAMP server, and the two PHP applications share the same MySQL database, do I need to worry about data integrity during concurrent database transactions, or is this something that MySQL just takes care of "natively"?

What happens if the two PHP applications both try to update the same record at the same time? What happens if they try to update the same table at the same time? What happens if they both try to read data from the database at the same time? Or if one application tries to read a record at the same time as the other application is updating that record?

Comment: It depends on your database software and drivers but in general this isn't something you need to worry about. MySQL will [queue](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/concurrent-inserts.html) them in some order rather than getting upset at transactions occuring at the same time. Read about locks if you want to know specific behaviour about updating/reading.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> What happens if the two PHP applications both try to update the same  record at the same time? 
>
> What happens if they try to update the same table at the same time? 
>
> What happens if they both try to read data from the database at the same time? 
> Or if one application tries to read a record at the same time as the other application is updating that record?
> ```

This depend from several factor  ..

the db engine you are using

the locking policy  / transaction you have setted  for you envirement .. or for you query 
    https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html
    https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html

the code you are using  ..  you could use a select for update for lock only the rows  you want modify 
    https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

and how you manage transaction
    https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html

this is just a brief suggestion